# filtrar div por horas con jquery range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

Tengo un slider por horas, con el cual me gustaría filtrar div dependiendo de su horario ej:

```js
$("#slider-container2").slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 1440,
    step: 15,
    values: [0, 1440],
    slide: function (e, ui) {
        var hours1 = Math.floor(ui.values[0] / 60);
        var minutes1 = ui.values[0] - (hours1 * 60);
        

        if (hours1.length == 1) hours1 = '0' + hours1;
        if (minutes1.length == 1) minutes1 = '0' + minutes1;
        if (minutes1 == 0) minutes1 = '00';
        if (hours1 >= 12) {
            if (hours1 == 12) {
                hours1 = hours1;
                minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
            } else {
                hours1 = hours1 - 12;
                minutes1 = minutes1 + " PM";
            }
        } else {
            hours1 = hours1;
            minutes1 = minutes1 + " AM";
        }
        if (hours1 == 0) {
            hours1 = 12;
            minutes1 = minutes1;
        }



        $('.slider-time').html(hours1 + ':' + minutes1);

        var hours2 = Math.floor(ui.values[1] / 60);
        var minutes2 = ui.values[1] - (hours2 * 60);

        if (hours2.length == 1) hours2 = '0' + hours2;
        if (minutes2.length == 1) minutes2 = '0' + minutes2;
        if (minutes2 == 0) minutes2 = '00';
        if (hours2 >= 12) {
            if (hours2 == 12) {
                hours2 = hours2;
                minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
            } else if (hours2 == 24) {
                hours2 = 11;
                minutes2 = "59 PM";
            } else {
                hours2 = hours2 - 12;
                minutes2 = minutes2 + " PM";
            }
        } else {
            hours2 = hours2;
            minutes2 = minutes2 + " AM";
        }
        

        $('.slider-time2').html(hours2 + ':' + minutes2);
        
    }  
});
```

```css
.red1 {
background-color:red;
color:white;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.green1 {
background-color:green;
color:white;
margin-top: 20px;
}

.yellow1 {
background-color:yellow;
color:black;
margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<span class="slider-time">10:00 AM</span> - <span class="slider-time2">12:00 PM</span>
<br><br>
<div id="slider-container2"></div>

<br><br>

<div class="red1" data-hour="7:00am">
7:00 AM
</div>

<div class="green1" data-hour="1:45pm">
1:45 PM
</div>

<div class="yellow1" data-hour="6:30pm">
6:30 PM
</div>
```

¿Cual sería la manera correcta de realizarlo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero hay que agrupar los *divs* a filtrar en otro `div`, en mi caso lo voy a llamar `tiempos`.

En el deslizador el cambio mínimo es 15 minutos, la cantidad de **cuartos de hora** que hay en un día es 24 por 4, que eso es 96, pero esa tarea se la dejo a *JavaScript*.

Para generar el texto **3:00 AM a 5:15 PM** hago una serie de cálculos, basado en **el cuarto de hora número tal**. Ejemplo, si el deslizador está entre las 3 AM y las 5:15 PM, eso internamente son cantidades de cuartos de hora. 3 horas son 12 cuartos, y 5:15 son 5*4 + 1, son 21, a eso se le suma el *PM*, que son 12 horas multiplicado por 4, es decir, 48, y sumado 21 son 69.

Lo que hago es convertir 12 y 69 mediante una serie de cálculos para que muestre **3:00 AM a 5:15 PM**, haciendo la operación inversa. Con operadores ternarios (`a==2?b:c`) hago comprobaciones para mostrar correctamente cuando es *AM* o *PM*, o convertir por ejemplo, *23* en *11 PM*.

Para filtrar es muy simple, lo que hago es transformar las horas a números comparables, es decir, *5:15 PM*, que son 69 cuartos de hora, lo divido por 4 y da *17,25*, ese número lo verifico con los rangos del deslizador, que también los convierto a números decimales. Si coincide con el rango, lo muestra, de lo contrario lo oculta.

La serie de pasos que hago para resolverlo es la siguiente.

1. Obtengo todos los `div` que hay en `tiempos`.
2. Hago una matriz con  los atributos `data-hour`, en la primera columna los `div`, en la segunda, las horas.

   ```
   [
        [<div ...>, "7:00am"]
       ,[<div ...>, "1:45pm"]
       ,[<div ...>, "6:30pm"]
   ]
   ```
3. Le aplico una expresión regular para separar la hora en 3 partes.

   ```
   "1:45pm" -> ["1", "45", "pm"]
   ```
4. Convierto las 3 partes en un solo número decimal.

   ```
   ["1", "45", "pm"] -> 1 + 45/60 + 12 // Solamente en PM se suma 12
   ```
5. Uso `$(div).hide()` o `$(div).show()` para ocultar o mostrar según el número decimal esté entre el rango del deslizador.

Código:

```js
$("#slider-container").slider({
 range: true,
 min: 0,
 max: 24*4,
 step: 1,
 values: [0, 24*4],
 slide: function (e, ui) {
  var horas_slider = ui.values.map(x=>x/4)
  var horas_slider_formateado = horas_slider.map(
   x=>Math.floor(x>=13?x%12:x)
    +":"+(((x%1)*60+100)+"").slice(1)
    +" "+(x>=12&x<24?"PM":"AM")
  ).join(" a ")
  $(".slider-time").html(horas_slider_formateado)
  var horas_contenidos = (
   Array.from($("#tiempos>div"))
   .map(x=>[x,$(x)
    .attr("data-hour")
    .match(/\d+|[a-z]+/g)
   ]).map(
    x=>[x[0],
    +x[1][0]+(+x[1][1]/60)+(+(x[1][2]=="pm")*12)]
   ).map(x=>{
    if((x[1]>=horas_slider[0]&&x[1]<=horas_slider[1])){
     $(x[0]).show()
    }else{
     $(x[0]).hide()
    }
   })
  )
 }
});
```

```css
.rojo {
 background-color: red;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.verde {
 background-color: green;
 color: white;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.amarillo {
 background-color: yellow;
 color: black;
 margin-top: 20px;
}
.deslizador {
 margin-left: 10px;
 margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<p class="slider-time">0:00 AM a 0:00 AM</p>

<div id="slider-container" class="deslizador"></div>

<div id="tiempos" >
  <div class="rojo" data-hour="7:00am">7:00 AM</div>
  <div class="verde" data-hour="1:45pm">1:45 PM</div>
  <div class="amarillo" data-hour="6:30pm">6:30 PM</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Excelente! Funcionando!

Una duda: En el código anterior se mostraban las horas en formato 24. Ej: 22:00 PM, y ahora en formato 12 (10:00 PM). Hay alguna manera de volver al formato 24?

Comment: @EliasAria Pones `var horas_slider_formateado = horas_slider` y borras desde `map` hasta el `join`, y el `join` lo mantienes.

Comment: Aplicando ésto desaparece el AM y PM del slider, y el formato queda asi: 7.15 22.00, etc. ¿O estoy haciendo algo mal?

Comment: @EliasAria Ah, cierto... Tiene que quedar así. `var horas_slider_formateado = horas_slider.map(x=>Math.floor(x)+":"+(((x%1)*60+100)+"").slice(1)).join(" a ")`

Comment: Bien, ahí el formato queda bien! Pero no muestra el AM y PM, ¿a que se debe? https://jsfiddle.net/alejandrov90/wvLo915k/2/

Comment: @EliasAria Es que el formato de 24 horas no necesita tener AM o PM, porque es más general. No hay que ponerlo.

Comment: excelente! Quedó funcionando correctamente así! Gracias!